# java -version is not displayed in the console

Tags: java, cmd, version

There was such a problem:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Oleg>echo %JAVA_HOME%
D:\Documents\java\versions\jdk20

C:\Users\Oleg>java

C:\Users\Oleg>java -version

C:\Users\Oleg>java -v

C:\Users\Oleg>
```

The java version is not output, although JAVA_HOME is registered and defined in PATH
[JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCui1.png), [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuTrc.png)

Maybe someone has faced a similar problem? When deleting '\' in PATH, nothing changes

Comment: You can possibly start by trying `set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%";java -version` I would get rid of that Oracle Java path

Comment: @g00se it's windows. You meant `set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"` (and yes, I know that *looks* wrong).

Comment: I'm referring to `C:\Program Files...Oracle\Java\javapath` And yes, I probably *did* mean that

Comment: thank you, everything works. I spent almost an hour on it..

Comment: There is never a need to add things to `Path`. All you needed to do was use proper code instead of lazy and inefficient shorthand. ```"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version```. Also, if you should have a need you should not just blindly prepend the variable, you should append; ```Set "Path=%Path%%JAVA_HOME%\bin;"```. Irrespective, the file has an extension, which you should **always** use.

Comment: ?? I don't know where to start...

Comment: Would you like assistance @g00se? BTW, I agree that the Oracle location could be problematic, because of its position, however, there cannot be a file with the basename `java` and any extension listed within the `PathExt` variable there, otherwise it's version would have been reported instead, _(not shown)_.

Comment: @Compo you are being inappropriately pedantic and stating an exotic approach to command line management as gospel. Separate from the merits of your approach, yelling at g00se isn't an appropriate way to interact with others, and that dictatorial tone isn't helpful.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, my comment neither yelled nor dictated, it was a response to the their questioning. If they wished some form of clarification, they should have asked instead of insinuating. My comment part agreed with them, yet showed that based upon the OP information, their suggestion was not a fix, _(despite the OP's response to it)_, and explained why. Also, they'd already been corrected by Elliott Frisch in a much less respectful way.

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) There is explained in full details how `cmd.exe` searches for a file of which just the file name without file extension and without path is entered by a user or specified in a batch file. The environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not evaluated by `cmd.exe` at all. There can be executed `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe java` to find out which file is found on using just `java` by `where.exe` and also by `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I recommend to read the Oracle documentation page [The java Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html) and [Installation of the JDK on Microsoft Windows Platforms](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html). (Shame on Oracle writing `DOS Mode` and `MS-DOS shell` because of the __Windows Command Prompt__ is __not__ a `MS-DOS shell` or a `DOS Mode`.)

Comment: BTW in windows command line we can use the `path %JAVA_HOME%;%PATH%` without `set` and `=`

Answer (score 0):

First, try `"java -version"` command from the path `D:\Documents\java\versions\jdk20` where you have it.

If it shows the version set the environment variable as shown below in your machine:

[image]

After that, try `"java -version"` from any location.